# how to multiply values in an array of numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

```
var timeCost =[];
var ride_time = 30;
var cost_per_minute = [0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45];

for (let i = 0; i < cost_per_minute.length; i++ ){
  timeCost.push(cost_per_minute[i]*ride_time) 
}

console.log(timeCost)
```

Comment: timeCost.push(cost_per_minute[i]*ride_time) ... please have a look at the console first, it will tell you that [i]* is invalid

Comment: The length of the "cost_per_minute" value, is 4, so this loop is never going to run!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two places in your code:

The 2nd part of a for loop is commonly a condition of the counter (i.e. `i`) being less than the total count of the array (.ie. `cost_per_minute.length`)

> for (var i = 0; `i < cost_per_minute.length;` i++ ){

The syntax for an element within an array is `nameOfArray[i]` with `i` as the variable index number.

> timeCost.push(`cost_per_minute[i]`*ride_time)

}

```js
var timeCost =[];

var  ride_time = 30;

var cost_per_minute = [0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45];

for (let i = 0; i < cost_per_minute.length; i++ ){

  timeCost.push(cost_per_minute[i]*ride_time) 

}


console.log(timeCost)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is far more concise with `.map()`:

```
let cost_per_minute...
const ride_time = 30;
let timeCost = cost_per_minute.map(x => x * ride_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ride_time = 30;
var cost_per_minute = [0.2, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45]
var timeCost = cost_per_minute.map(function(i){return i* ride_time})
console.log(timeCost)
```